# Current state of Cassandra on Windows and what migration path?

Tags: windows, cassandra, migration

I am currently involved in a project to scale-up an existing Windows Cassandra cluster because we are planning to migrate large amounts of historic data. However, I am a bit skeptical to keep using Windows for the nodes. I have done some research about Cassandra on Windows and found some releasenotes that there is official support for Windows since 2.2.x. but since then I can not find any mention of Windows support.

I was wondering what the current state of Cassandra is on windows?

Second question; I we do decide to switch to Linux, would the following migration path work? 
1. Set-up a new Linux cluster and have our incoming data stream into the existing Windows and new Linux cluster. 
2. Use the SSTableloader to stream the existing SSTables to the Linux cluster. 
3. Switch the endpoint of the application to the new Linux cluster.

Would this work even if we have incoming live data that share the paritionkeys with the data that needs to be migrated? Could the timestamps or tombstones cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

To put a historical perspective on it, there have been two main problems with Cassandra on Windows:

- deleting files, which other processes have open handles to ([CASSANDRA-4050](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-4050))
- memory-mapped file I/O, which is problematic in Windows with hard links ([CASSANDRA-9658](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9658))

These have been addressed in Cassandra 2.2.

That being said, in the grand scheme of things Cassandra on Windows is still a very new thing.  I don't recall seeing a lot of Windows-specific issues in the Cassandra JIRA, dev or user forums, but the potential for it still exists.  So your best chances for running a successful cluster would be to do it on Linux, which is a long-running, tried and true solution.

<personalBias>If it were me, I would ***not*** want to support a Cassandra cluster on Windows.</personalBias>

I think your migration path will work.  But the easier route would be to build your Linux nodes as a new logical data center, and join them to the existing cluster.  Then, once replication has completed, you can decommission your Windows nodes/DC, and that should save you from having to do your 2nd step.

Comment: He Aaron, thanks for the quick reply. About the easier route; is that even possible to mix different OSs inside the same cluster?